# short list of recently changed pages in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm using mediawiki to run a wiki for my (relatively small <10 users) team and would like to know if its possible to get a short list of, say, the last 5 changed pages to appear in the side bar.  I know I can go to recent changes page, but my users are used to seeing a list of the most recent changed pages on every page.

Thanks

Comment: [example](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Recent_changes)

Comment: I can't get the transclude of the recent changes to work in the side bar. Nothing shows up.  Thanks for the tip regarding limiting the number of results returned

Comment: What do you mean in the sidebar? Like on http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Sidebar? I don't imagine that can accept transcludes, I think it would be too intensive for the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw here that you got a hack to put wikitext into the sidebar: http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?15842-Show-recent-changes-in-sidebar

Try transcluding the recent changes into a template, then putting that template in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I could get it to work. I even tried the CustomNavBlock extension but that didn't work either as it seem to not want to render the RecentChanges page in the sidebar.

Comment: I think it might be blocked in code somewhere, maybe you could change it.